# How do I implement a dynamic theme in an ionic app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, themes

I am making an ionic application and I have a view that allows users to change the color scheme of the app. How would I implement this? If I use ng-class on every element in the app to dynamically change the colors it might lead to overloading the main UI thread since each ng-class will add a new watcher and there are a lot of pages and elements in this app.

Comment: Maybe an ng-class on only the body and using inheritence would do the trick !

Comment: Can you give me an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an ng-class on only the body and using inheritence would do the trick !

**HTML**

```
<body ng-class="vm.color">
    <div class="title">
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.red .title {
    background: red;
}

.blue .title {
    background: red;
}
```